# Does the spell Snowsong move with me once cast?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, area-of-effect

The area of the *snowsong* spell (*Frostburn*, p. 105) is listed as "30-ft. radius centered on you". Does this mean that the spell moves with me once cast?

This seems like an amazing spell, but only if it moves with me. I have yet to find anything online to tell me whether it does so or not.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Kevin_Goon Your question would be much better if it listed where this spell is from, especially from an older system that has reams of books. How ever I am going to assume this is from Forstburn.

Answer (score 4):

## The *snowsong* is stationary

Were the *snowsong* spell effect to move with the caster, the spell would likely have header entries like those of the 6th-level Sor/Wiz spell [*antimagic field*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsAtoB.html#antimagic-field) [conj] (*PH* 200) and be, instead, an [emanation](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#burst-emanation-or-spread): "An emanation spell functions like a burst spell, except that the effect continues to radiate from the point of origin for the duration of the spell" (*PH* 175). The *snowsong* spell effect's *not* an emanation and has no special rules saying otherwise, so its effect stays where it was put like most other non-emanation effects that don't specify otherwise.

In other words, the 6th-level bard spell ***snowsong*** [evoc] (*Frostburn* 105) creates an immobile area. Although the spell's area is measured from the caster, like the similar 1st-level Sor/Wiz [*obscuring mist*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#obscuring-mist) [conj] (*Player's Handbook* 258) and the extremely similar 6th-level bard spell *dirge* [evoc] (*Spell Compendium* 65), the *snowsong* spell effect is stationary.

Just to be clear, the *snowsong* spell's description begins with the following:

> When you cast the spell, you must designate **all** creatures in the area as either allies or enemies. (*Fr* 105)

And it ends with this:

> These benefits remain in place as long as the spell persists and as long as the target remains in the spell’s area. If **a creature** leaves the spell’s area, all effects end for that creature until it returns to the *snowsong*’s area. (*ibid.*)

(Emphases mine.) Needless to say, casters usually designate themselves as allies and tend to want to stay in that area. (Its immobility is also likely why [this guide](https://www.joshuad.net/new-bard-handbook/) lists the *snowsong* spell as only an average spell choice for the typical bard.)

---

***Note:*** While the mist *spell's description says that its effect "is stationary once created," this reader assumes that this reminder is because of the spell's status as a 1st-level spell, its clarification right there so players new to the spell needn't look up these rules. Because of its* Range *entry a DM may rule that a caster* can *affect spells like* obscuring mist *and* snowsong *with the* Complete Arcane *feat Persistent Spell (81) (see, for example, [here](https://forums.giantitp.com/showsinglepost.php?p=8599614&postcount=22); in such cases, effects would remain for 24 hours right there where they were cast, totally immobile.*

Comment: As an additional example to antimagic field: Prismatic Sphere uses the exact same wording of "XX-ft.-radius sphere centered on you", without mention of being a Burst, Emanation, or Spread and is a stationary spell.

Comment: @L.P.  Thank you! When an edit is due I'll include that as a further example.

Comment: @L.P. Prismatic Sphere is explicitly immobile, though. So I don't think it really counts. Globe of Invulnerability is also explicitly immobile, even though it is an emanation.

More importantly, Prismatic Sphere is an effect spell, not an area spell. The same is true for Obscuring Mist.

Answer (score 1):

### Probably, but the spell's description provides no conclusive evidence.

While *snowsong* is not explicitly defined as an emanation anywhere in its text, it was probably intended to be one (and thus move with the caster), because that specific wording you quoted is most likely a misprint.

Firstly, any spell with fixed [*area*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#area) and [*range*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#range) entries that is explicitly centered on the caster is consistently described as a burst, spread or emanation throughout 3.5 sources. That "radius centered on you" wording with no other clarification would make *snowsong* the **only** exception in published 3.5 material. This strongly points to sloppy editing as the most likely cause for the omission.

No term or sentence in the spell's description unambiguously indicates whether the effect is static. In fact, the way *snowsong* works seems to suggest otherwise: like any emanation, it affects only creatures entering or remaining in the area, as the spell's text clearly states.

Considering area+range, effect and duration, the spell most closely resembles other buff auras centered on the caster, which tend to move with the character unless otherwise specified. Examples include *aura of evasion* and *cloak of bravery* from the *Spell Compendium* or *linked perception* and *longstrider, mass* from the *Player's Handbook II*, among others. Even the *dirge* spell, used in the previous answer as an example of a spell similar to *snowsong*, is quite oddly [a burst that actually behaves like an emanation](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#burst-emanation-or-spread). This is likely due to a slip by the designer updating the original *Magic of Faerun* version, which shows how unfixed errors are common in spell descriptions.

While none of this rules out other interpretations completely, *snowsong* being an emanation that moves with the caster as point of origin would be both the simplest explanation and the most consistent ruling considering how similarly worded spells usually work. That said, given the spell's ambiguous text and the lack of any official errata or FAQ, any DM will probably still want to have the last word about it.